# Number of root solutions to a cubic curve in two variables

Tags: number-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have a physical geometric problem that yields two distinction equations for unknowns $x$ and $y$, which look something like

Eq1: $Ax^4y + Bx^4 + Cx^3y^2 + Dx^3y + Ex^3 + Fx^2y^3 + Gx^3y^2...+Hy^3 + I = 0$,

and Eq2: $Jx^3y^2 + Kx^3y + Lx^3 + Mx^2y + Nx^2y^2 + Oxy^3 +...+Py^3 + Q = 0$,

where $A-J$ are known constants. I'm solving this as a simultaneous equation numerically, looking specifically looking for the real positive solutions which I can readily find. But in the examples I've toyed with so far, I'm getting around 18 pairs of solutions for $x$ and $y$ total. My question is, is there any way of predicting how many solutions I should expect in general? For example, in a typical cubic equation in one variables, I'd expect 3 solutions. But is there a way of predicting how many solutions I should expect for more complicated two-variables cases like this?

Comment: These appear to be degree 5 curves, so you can use Bezout's theorem to place an upper bound of 25 points. You might be able to narrow this down a bit more by solving for the "points at infinity" in the projective plane and subtract the number of those points off.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, thanks! If you want to add it as an answer, happy to accept...